# How can I change the property of overflow-y depending of the height?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to put visible the following property : `overflow-y-visible` if the height is too small and else `overflow-y-hidden` using tailwind css and react.

I don't know how can I do that, I mean with width I know but with height I cannot use sm, md etc ...

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Hi Paul, to answer this question can you post a minimal, reproducible example. See here for further details https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Thanks

Comment: @orghu, your edit is wrong.. this is tailwind-css and the classes should be declared in the way the author did (`overflow-y-visible` and `overflow-y-hidden`)..

Comment: @ChenBr, oh, okay ...sorry.

Comment: "Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed." ...it has been awhile.

Comment: @orghu Yeah.. probably my edit haha

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS media feature to target specific height of the viewport:

```css
.container {
  height:30px;
  overflow-y:hidden
}

@media (min-height: 100px) {
  .container {
    overflow-y:visible
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Create custom [Tailwind media queries](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#customizing-breakpoints):

Create your custom media queries using the `raw` key inside `tailwind.config.js`, for example:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'smh': { 'raw': '(min-height: 640px)' },
        // => @media (min-height: 800px) { ... }
       
        'mdh': { 'raw': '(min-height: 800px)' },
        // => @media (min-height: 800px) { ... }

        'lgh': { 'raw': '(min-height: 1240px)' },
        // => @media (min-height: 1240px) { ... }

       'xlh': { 'raw': '(min-height: 1600px)' },
        // => @media (min-height: 1600px) { ... }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Media queries defined using the raw key will be output as-is, and the min and max keys will be ignored.

You can use any name you want, I used `smh`, `mdh`, `lgh` and `xlh` but I could also use `random`, `something` and `tallerscreen`. It doesn't matter how you name it as long as the name makes sense to you.

---

Those responsive utilities act like the width [media queries](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design). For example, you can type the following code (after adding the custom responsive utilities to `tailwind.config.js`) to set your border to red when the screen height is taller than 640px and to blue when it's shorter than 640px:

```
<div class="border-4 border-blue-500 smh:border-red-500">test</div>
```

Here's a tailwind-play link with the example above: [Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/6lrBkUAf9G).

---

In the same way, you can write something like this to hide and show your `overflow-y` utility:

```
<div class="h-[5rem] overflow-y-hidden border-4 smh:overflow-y-visible">
  <div>Text.................</div>
  <div>Text.................</div>
  <div>Text.................</div>
  <div>Text.................</div>
  <div>Text.................</div>
</div>
```

When the window height exceeds 640px, anything that flows out of the div is visible. If the window height is shorter than 640px, anything that flows out of the div is hidden.
[Tailwind-play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/hHkKQ7nELl)